# get .html() of {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, meteor

I have a `$('.textarea').val()` that gets the value of said textarea upon submission, inserts it into a `Mongo.Collection` and then displays it through `{{#each}}{{/each}}` in the body.

Before the text is inserted into the collection and then returned & published again, I have a regex set up to replace all image links with `<img src='said link'>`

My issue is that .val() does not work with tags, only `.html` and `.text` does, which I cannot use to get the value of a textarea. Is there any clever way of going about this (replacing .val() with .html()? Perhaps a listener on the body to replace all links with the tag after the text has already been submitted, in which case, how would I go about setting it up to listen for all text change?

EDIT:

To be more precise, is there a way to perform

```
$('.messages').html($('.messages).html().replace(this, 'that'))
```

on values that are constantly changing and output by `{{#each}}`
 after returned from a collection? Is there a way to refer to each of the messages rather than whole?

Comment: what if you do it like: `var tempHTML = $('.messages).html(); tempHTML = tempHTML.replace('this', 'that'); $('.messages').html(tempHTML)`?

Comment: no, because I need to refer to each individual message that comes from {{#each}}{{>message}}{{#each}} and then replace it. If I refer to all messages it messes them all up. problem is i don't know how to refer to each individual msg's html

Comment: Indeed it'll be a mess, Now how about this code instead https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L58ukj6j/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to replace all the sources in a text with images. This should help you:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/replacing-text-links-with-images

Also, read this part of the jquery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

I think that you are on the right track: changing the .html() should work.

Comment: Yes, however I don't get how to edit the .html() as it is not static. Per se $('.textOutput').html($('.textOutput').html().replace(textOutput, 'editedOutput')); wouldn't work, since the output is split into messages and the messages each are unique and constantly new ones are being added.  Meaning that if I do that it will just ruin all of the messages